# Cannot find source for binding with reference when using context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've read other cases posted here un StackOverflow about this message but I'm not clear how to apply the changes to my problem. I have a small application made with WPF and my ignorance of xaml is taking its toll. I compile and everything is fine but when running in debug mode, in the output window in VS2015 I see
**System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=lbEnfermedades'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandTarget' (type 'IInputElement')**
I see that I'm not the only one having problems with context menus. I created a class using RoutedUICommand as suggested:

```
namespace Maqueta
{
    class CommandLibrary
    {
        private static RoutedUICommand relacionados = new RoutedUICommand("Relacionados", "BuscarRelacionados", typeof(CommandLibrary));

        public static RoutedUICommand BuscarRelacionados
        {
            get { return relacionados; }
        }

    }
}
```

I have this portion of Xaml, maybe the nesting of controls I'm doing is forbidden? In a tabcontrol I put a listbox and then attached a context menu:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="287" Margin="10,243,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="709" TabStripPlacement="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TabItem Header="Enfermedades">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbEnfermedades" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu IsEnabled="True" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
                    <MenuItem Command="local:CommandLibrary.BuscarRelacionados"
                              CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=lbEnfermedades}"
                              Header="BuscarRelacionados" IsEnabled="True"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ListBox.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="local:CommandLibrary.BuscarRelacionados" CanExecute="CanBuscarRelacionadosExecute" Executed="OnBuscarRelacionadosExecute" />
            </ListBox.CommandBindings>
            <CheckBox/>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Medicamentos">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbMedicamentos" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Procedimientos">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbProcedimientos" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I also created the routines that should be called, using another post here as an example:

```
private void OnBuscarRelacionadosExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    if (lb != null)
    {
        if (lb.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            //lb.Items.Remove(lv.SelectedItem);
            MessageBox.Show(lb.SelectedItem.ToString());
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}

private void CanBuscarRelacionadosExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
    if (lb != null)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;//lb.SelectedItem != null;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

These methods are never called and the context menu appears grayed (disabled) when I right click on the listbox. I understand this is because the "cannot find source for binding" message. Any pointers to a throrough explanation of xaml binding would be appreciated because the tips I see in other posts (for example, "use relative binding") are a mystery for me. Couldn't find the definive doc at Microsoft site either. I wish using context menues were a more intuitive task. Thanks.

Claudio.

Answer (score 1):

The CommandTarget attribute of your context menu is superfluous.  The error message you are seeing simply means that the command target is ignored.  So take out command target.  The command binding that you have defined for the list box will be the command target.

Despite that, your context menu works for me with or without the CommandTarget attribute...so something else is wrong in a part of your code you haven't shared with us.

Your XAML, routed command implementation and command binding all look fine.  So it seems to me that you are looking in the wrong place for the problem...a common symptom that arises when your binding are not working.

Unfortunately cannot refer you to a "thorough explanation of [WPF] binding" because all the stuff you need to master is scattered among diverse sources.  The only explanations of binding that exist in one place are see-spot-run...and you are well beyond that.

In my experience the only way to explore the intricacies of binding is maintain a set of test code you can experiment on.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the person that took the time to answer. I continued looking for ideas in this site but nothing seemed to help. Finally, today I added a little part:

```
<MenuItem Command="local:CommandLibrary.BuscarRelacionados"
      CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=local:lbEnfermedades}"
      Header="BuscarRelacionados" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

I changed ElementName=lbEnfermedades to
ElementName=local:lbEnfermedades. I don't know why it's necessary, it was just a wild hunch. Now the event handlers I defined are working as expected and my menu item is not disabled anymore when the context menu appears. Hope someone else may find it useful.